# Physics dealing with distance

Tags: physics

The distance $s$ in feet that a thrown object will fall in $t$ seconds is given by

$$s=16t^2 + vt\;,$$

where $v$ is the initial downward velocity in feet/second.  Find the initial velocity of an object that falls $80$ feet in $2$ seconds.

Comment: What have you done? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  you have three unknowns in the equation and are provided values for two of them.

Answer (score 1):

So you have

- $s =$ distance
- $v =$ initial velocity
- $t =$ time.

You have these related via:
$$
s = 16t^2 + tv. 
$$

Now if the distance $d= 80$ (feet) and the time is $t = 2$ (sec.), you know two of the three variables, so you can solve for the third. I.e., start with
$$
80 = 16(2)^2 + 2v.
$$
This is a (linear) equation with just one unknown that you can solve for.